# Remove the Top and Bottom background color of Dropdown Items

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have TextInputLayout in which I am using text autocomplete and implementing a dropdown menu for gender. problem is that the white color shown on the top and bottom in the background of the dropdown items.I have given the background color yellow.[image]

This is my XML

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutGender"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:hint="Gender"
        android:textColorHint="#858585"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="45dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="45dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="45dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="45dp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/edit_textbox_color"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
        app:endIconTint="#FFC153"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/yellow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewInformation"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/sex"
            android:drawablePadding="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:textColor="@color/yellow" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This I am used for Dropdown items

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:padding="14dp"
    >

</com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView>
```

Comment: set drop-down layout background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to apply background drawable programmatically like below:

```
autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(
    context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yellow_drawable));
```

Create `yellow_drawable.xml` with solid yellow color.

Comment: or programmatically `new ColorDrawable(color)` where `color` is created by `ContextCompat.getColor` pointing on `R.color.yellow` - same as set for background for `TextView`

Comment: i have used this line it solved but I did not know how?? because I have passed code of white color "gender.setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("#fff"));

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background image of the dropdown using

```
setDropDownBackgroundResource();
```

[Here is the official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView#setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))